# Genexus: Use of Collection Variable in For Each

Tags: genexus

I'm getting an error when I'm using a variable collection inside a For Each command:

```
For each
   where itemId in &items
   ...
   ...
   ...
EndFor
```

Where &items is a collection variable of Attribute itemId

How can I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pablo, What error are you having?

I suspect that ItemId (based on its name) is not at itesm.item type and should be that type.
&Items collection of item
&Item is defined as &items.item

```
for &Item in &items()
    &Item.Id
endfor
```

please check this link for further information: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8585,For%20In%20Array%2FCollection%20Command

Gustavo

Answer (score 1):

```
&items: varchar
&oneItem: varchar
&colItems: numeric - collection: true

&items = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7....'

For &oneItem In &items.SplitRegEx(',')
    &colItems.Add(&oneItem.ToNumeric())
EndFor 

For each
   where itemId in &colItems
   ...
   ...
   ...
EndFor
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. Instead of just including the code, can you edit your answer to also offer an explanation of your code? Why does this solve the problem? What's the most relevant part of your code?

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have the error message.

Syntax seems ok to me, assuming you are trying to retrieve from the table the records that match the values in &items collection.

Answer (score 0):

> For each    where itemId in **&items**    ...    ...    ... EndFor

Pablo,
I can't see any error. Your code's ok... but, maybe the definitions of &Items could be wrong. Please, you should check that ITEMS is a var of the ItemId type and that it is also a collection.

```
Program....: PabloForIn.wbp
```

&colItemId: VarChar(40) - collection: true

*/

Event Start
&colItemId.add('3')
&colItemId.add('7')

EndEvent //Start

Event Load
For Each //Items
Where ItemId in &ColItemId

```
    &ItemId     = ItemId //Grid of &ItemsId
    load
EndFor
```

EndEvent //Load

I am attaching 3 Images
1 Variable &ColItemId must be Collection
[image]

2 Objects
[image]

3 Running

[image]